# Service dependencies not shown in Jaeger between Spring Boot Applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, opentracing, jaeger

I'm currently trying to trace two Spring Boot (2.1.1) applications with Jaeger using https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentracing-spring-web-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

also tryed with no success

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The tracing of the Spans for every single service / app works fine, but not over REST requests on a global level.
There is no dependency shown between the services like you can see in the image.

[image: Missing App in trace between 2 Apps]

Shouldn't this work out of the box through the library? Or do I have to implement some interceptors and request filters by my own and if so, how?

**You can CHECKOUT a minimalistic project containing the problem** [here](https://github.com/derXear/opentracing-spring-boot-jaeger-example)

Btw: Jaeger runs as all-in-one via docker and works as expected

```
docker run \
--rm \
--name jaeger \
-p5775:5775/udp \
-p6831:6831/udp \
-p6832:6832/udp \
-p5778:5778 \
-p16686:16686 \
-p14268:14268 \
-p9411:9411 \
jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();` to get an instance of the `RestTemplate` to make a REST call.

Doing that means that Opentracing cannot instrument the call to add necessary HTTP headers.

Please consider using `@Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using a more recent version of Jaeger: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/latest/getting-started/#all-in-one - actually 1.11 is now out, so could try that.

Comment: actually i do use 'latest'. I edited my question to fix that. Thanks anyway.